# Are there tools within ROS to help me create my operator interface?

Tags: control, ros, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Newbie warning.  If this is a stupid question, please be patient.  :-)

I have installed ROS Hydro.  I have run through all the beginners tutorials ... so I have created publisher nodes, subscriber nodes, message types, services, and clients.  I have also worked through most of the Gazebo tutorials, so I feel like I understand how to write software on my robot and how to test that software using the simulator.  But I have not come across anything yet about human operator graphical interfaces.

What is the robot development community typically using to create their operator GUIs and how do those GUIs typically communicate with the robot? I have not found anything on this topic, so I'm assuming that there are no tools bundled with ROS to help me with this part of my robot software suite.

Any help is greatly appreciated.   Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/138151/are-there-tools-within-ros-to-help-me-create-my-operator-interface?/) by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on ROS Answers with karma: 486 on 2014-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[rqt](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt) is a Qt-based framework for GUI development for ROS where you can write your own GUIs or use the ones already developed.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2014-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on 2014-03-10**:
Thank you!  I wish that was listed on the ROS Tutorial page.  I don't know how newbies are supposed to find out about all the most common or most basic capabilities of ROS.  It's very confusing to me.